# Joined results as column names

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have this Mysql scenario

```
table1
--------------
id   `7`   `8`
--------------
1    10    20
2    20    30

table 2
---------------
id  code   rel
---------------
3     7     1
4     8     2
```

I am using following statement to get values

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.code, 
CASE t2.code WHEN 7 THEN (SELECT `7` FROM table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.rel)
CASE t2.code WHEN 8 THEN (SELECT `8` FROM table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.rel) 
END as val
FROM table2 t2
```

but it's neither pretty or functional, because I need these values summed, multiplied, etc, and there are a lot of columns.

Is there a way to join these tables and get table1.`7` value for t2.rel,t2.code values?
Something similar to

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.code, eval(t1.(t2.code))  as val
FROM table2 t2 
JOIN table1 t1 on t2.rel = t1.id
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is still relevant.

As you alredy know, there is no such thing as pivot in MySql, but aggregations might look rather easy if the number of columns is defined:

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(t2.code = 7, `7`, NULL)) as sum7,
  AVG(IF(t2.code=8, `8`, NULL)) as avg8
FROM t1 JOIN t2
  ON t1.id = t2.rel;
```

Answer (score 3):

Every column referenced in an SQL query must be fixed at the time you *prepare* the query.  There's no such thing as `eval`.

However you can use a data value to drive a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.code,
  CASE t2.code WHEN '7' THEN t1.`7` WHEN '8' THEN t1.`8` END AS `val`
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.rel = t1.id;
```

But you'd have to hard-code all the cases before you prepare the query.  There's no way for SQL to generate the expressions during execution time as it finds new `code` values on successive rows of data.

Comment: I misunderstood the original question, so I rewrote my answer.

Comment: yes, it's better to join and case, rather than case then select.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm curious if it is possible what your trying to do but this might be a solution for now.
Do a select like this:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.code, t1.*
FROM table2 t2 
JOIN table1 t1 on t2.rel = t1.id
```

Resulting in

```
  || *id* || *code* || *id* || *7* || *8* ||
  ------------------------------------------
  || 3    || 7      || 1    || 10  || 20  ||
  || 4    || 8      || 2    || 20  || 30  ||
```

Then in your code concatenate in your result. 
If your using php and your result is associative:

```
echo $result[$result['code']];
```

I don't think your going to make this happen in a query. You might want to rethink your database design.

Comment: yes, the best approach is to redesign database table1 table. bbut it's not a option at this time.... anyway, thank you!